# Adding new value and selecting clears previous selections - Select2 multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery

After some fun and games I finally worked out how to dynamically (on button press)  add and select a new value to a multiple Select2 select control populated from an MVC model on page load...

```
<select id="topicMaintMultiSelect" multiple="multiple" name="SelectedMaintTopic" tabindex="18" required="required">
    @foreach (var topic in Model.SystemTopics.AvailableTopics)
    {
        <option value=@topic.Value selected=@topic.Selected>@topic.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

...and...

```
function addTopic() {
    var newTopic = $("#NewTopic").val();
    var select = document.getElementById("topicMaintMultiSelect");

    var opt = new Option(newTopic, newTopic);
    select.options[select.options.length] = opt;
    opt.setAttribute("selected", "selected");

    $("#topicMaintMultiSelect").val(newTopic).trigger("change");

    $("#NewTopic").val("");
}
```

...but I cannot work out how to stop it from clearing the previously selected values.

I've tried a variety of suggested solutions, most of which are based on pushing a value into the select2 data but none of these seem to work, not sure why though.

Thoughts/suggestions, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the call to `.val(newTopic)`. That is what is clearing the previously selected values.

Adding an option that is marked as selected and triggering a change event is enough to change the value.

```
var newTopic = $('#NewTopic').val();

var $option = $('<option></option>').val(newTopic).text(newTopic).prop('selected', true);

$('#topicMaintMultiSelect').append($option).change();
```

[jsfiddle for Select2 v4](https://jsfiddle.net/co54a2sy/)

[jsfiddle for Select2 v3.5.3](http://jsfiddle.net/66hdbews/)

Comment: Oh, that is so elegant and so much more compact than mine.  Best of all... it works perfectly!  Thanks mate.